# Using both basic AND association mapping for one field with Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, mapping

I have a `Variable` object which may belong to a `group`

I'm mapping the `Variable` field containing the FK to the `Group`'s id **and** his relation association in my domain object. (using XMl).

In other words, my domain object has both a (string) field with the id and a "relation" field with the object.

*The intended goal here is to retrieve a ready* `Group` *object when querying, while simply setting an id when writing*

So when I create/update a `Variable`, I set the ID (not the relation Object).

My issue is : the value is (always) properly saved when I UPDATE, but (always) lost on INSERT.

Here's the part of my mapping :

```
    <field name="parentId" type="string" length="36" column="parent" nullable="true"/>
    <many-to-one field="parent" target-entity="App\Domain\VariablesGroup\VariablesGroup" fetch="EAGER">
        <join-column name="parent" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
```

Docs didn't help me much here, since those 2 mappings are described separetely, and might not be designed to be mixed this way.

--

But I'd prefer to avoid querying the `Group` from DB and populate the Object field when not necessary.

Since I didn't find how Doctrine handles this under the hood, I guess it might not be something supported :(

Technical precisions about this mappings-interraction (or should I say conflict ?) would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, some more testing, using inconsistent data entries in my entity seem to clearly demonstrate that such usage isn't intended.

Whild my code wouldn't allow this, if I do save my entity with groupId = 1 and Group = (group Object with ID 2), I get an alternance of values for the saved value in the "parent" column of my database.

I guess this is due to Doctrine skipping the "useless" update, and proceeding to the one which effectively changes the data value.
Since both values are different, the skipped update alternantes.

If my assumptions are right, Doctrine would better pop an error in such a mapping case. (as it does if you map one column to 2 fields).
Maybe I'll file a suggestion/issue, if this seem relevant.